# How do I setup bluetooth communication on windows 7 for my wireless Philips SHB4000 headphones?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio, drivers, bluetooth

[image]

I am having trouble initiating bluetooth communication with my wireless Philips SHB4000 headphones.  The picture provided above displays a quick overview of how far I have attempted to solve this problem. To summarize, I have installed windows moblie device center, changed peripheral drivers to microsoft drivers, downloaded the broadcom 820.11 drivers, downloaded microsoft bluetooth drivers. I am stuck on what to do next. How do I setup bluetooth communication on windows 7 for my wireless Philips SHB4000 headphones? Thanks.

Comment: have you succeeded already?

Comment: @LeosLiterak No I have not. When I have time I will try your solution. In the mean time enjoy my upvote. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This is my procedure that worked for me on Windows 7 32 bit:

1. install provider drivers ([Broadcom in my case)](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php)
2. reboot computer
3. Unpair the headphones
4. Pair again the headphones, drivers are found now
5. Setup Sound device
6. The headphones works